# Jenkins - execute system groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to execute a script by specifying its path (Groovy script file)
It's working fine, but there's a problem, i didn't find a way to pass args to the script, i'm not talking about the args of the job but a predefined args

Answer (score 0):

If you click on advanced on the system groovy build step, you will see "Variable bindings". You can populate this text window like a property file, and the left hand variables will be available as groovy unbound variables in your script.

If your goal is to use the same script from the command line and as a system groovy script, then just pass in the "args" array by entering, for example, the following into the advanced variable bindings text window:

```
args = ['test.groovy', 'arg1', 'arg2', ...]
```

Comment: what flags? what is it precisely you are trying to do?

Comment: Here's how I execute the script via the command line: ` groovy test.groovy "arg1" "arg2" ` how can I achieve it in Jenkins ?